# Question on adjunctions

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Let $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ be three categories. Let $F:\mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ be a functor, and let $G\dashv H$ be an adjunction, where $G:\mathcal{B}\to\mathcal{C}$ and $H:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{B}$.

If $G\circ F$ is to have a right adjoint, is it necessary that

i) there exists a functor $K:\mathcal{B}\to\mathcal{A}$? And, if yes,

ii) is $K$ right adjoint to $F$?

Answer (score 3):

i) Your assumptions imply that all three categories are either empty or nonempty simultaneously, so that there certainly exists *some* functor $B\to A.$ But that's not very interesting.

ii) There's no reason $F$ should have a right adjoint. For instance, if $A,C$ are both copies of the category with a single object and arrow, and if $B$ is a category with a terminal object, then your assumptions all hold. But $F$ will only have a right adjoint if it happens to send the object of $A$ to an initial object of $B$.

Comment: Thanks! What if $F$ is fully faithful? I think there is more hope then.

Comment: Glad to help! Your condition is still not enough. The same counterexample works if we take the value of $F$ to be any object with no nontrivial automorphisms which is nevertheless not initial.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth noting that there is at least one such object in this situation (provided $\mathcal{B}$ is not a pointed category), namely the terminal object in $\mathcal{B}$.